# convert one line values to multiple lines with numbering order

Tags: bash, awk, sed, printf, nc

The following variable include for example this values

```
echo $SERVERS


server1,server2,server3,server4,server5
```

and when I want to pipe them on different lines then I do the following

```
echo $SERVERS | tr ',' '\n'

server1
server2
server3
server4
server5
```

now I want to add another pipe `( echo $SERVERS | tr ',' '\n' | ..... )` , in order to print the following expected results

```
1  ………………  server1
2  ………………… server2
3  ………………… server3
4  ………………… server4
5  ………………… server5
6  ………………  server6
7  ………………… server7
8  ………………… server8
9  ………………… server9
10 ………………… server10
11 ………………… server11
12 ………………… server12
```

Not sure how to do it but maybe with `nc` command os similar

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With awk:

```
$ servers='server1,server2,server3,server4,server5'

$ awk -v RS=, '{print NR "........" $0}' <<<"$servers"
1........server1
2........server2
3........server3
4........server4
5........server5
```

or, to output the line numbers with left-padding

```
awk -v RS=, '{printf "%3d........%s\n",NR,$0}' <<<"$servers"
```

(choose the field width `3` as appropriate for the size of your server list).

Comment: is it possible to add printf , so it will be alignment when number are bigger then 10 ( I update my question )

Comment: @yael like `printf "%3d........%s\n",NR,$0`you mean? sure

Comment: yes , Iit will be great if you add this to your answer

Comment: That will print an extra blank line at the end of the output since `<<<` ensures the generated string has a terminating newline.

Comment: @EdMorton yes I realize that, I considered suggesting `<(printf '%s' "$servers")` but it seemed like overkill for what is likely a non-problem

Comment: You could be right but I feel like trailing blanks at the end of lines or trailing newlines at the end of output are something that don't get noticed at first and then they often cause some head-scratching down the road when they DO cause a problem and then people "fix" it by tacking on a pipe to some other command to remove them... so best just never to output them in the first place. The `printf` workaround you suggest has the problkem that it's output isn't a POSIX text file due to no terminating newline so YMMV with what any given tool will do with it (though it'll probably be OK).

Comment: OK fair enough - upvoting yours, will delete mine if @yael would be kind enough to un-accept it

Comment: No reason to delete it, it might be just fine for this particular OP, but it's always worth just stating any caveats especially when they're completely invisible in the output as in this case.

Answer (score 3):

```
cat -n <<< ${SERVERS//,/$'\n'} 
     1  server1
     2  server2
     3  server3
     4  server4
     5  server5
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ awk -F',' '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) printf "%-2d ........ %s\n", i, $i}' <<<"$servers"
1  ........ server1
2  ........ server2
3  ........ server3
4  ........ server4
5  ........ server5
```